# Is it possible to bypass RichTextBox input

Tags: c#

I have a RichTextBox (rtb_inputField). Whenever I type anything in this RTB, and press Enter, I send the string I typed to a server. I then put the same string back into rtb_inputField and select it programmatically (this way the user can send the same data quickly, simply by pressing enter again - or send another string by starting to type it.) All well and good so far.

Now what I want to do is: if NumLock is Locked and I press any of the numpad keys (0-9) I want to bypass rtb_inputField completely. By bypass I mean: not type any of the numbers into the RTB, and instead handle these numbers directly elsewhere. (I'm planning to quickly send data to the server this way, while the last command the user wrote in the RTB remains unchanged.)

But if NumLock is not Locked I want the numpad to put numbers into the RTB.

Is this possible and how?

Here's the code I have at the moment: (I have modified it so that you only see what's relevant for this question.)

```
private List<Keys> numPadList = new List<Keys>();

    private void populateNumPadList() {
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad0);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad1);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad2);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad3);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad4);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad5);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad6);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad7);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad8);
        numPadList.Add(Keys.NumPad9);
    }


    private void rtb_inputField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if ((numPadList.Contains(e.KeyData)) && (IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock))) {
            //The user pressed a numpad key
            MessageBox.Show("You pressed: " + e.KeyData.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;

        }

    }

    private void rtb_inputField_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        RichTextBox inputField = (RichTextBox)sender;
        string userInput = inputField.Text.Trim();

        if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) && (sender == rtb_inputField)) {

                if (client.Connected) {
                    macroString = runInputThroughMacroDictionary(userInput);

                    //do stuff..

                    writer.WriteLine(macroString);
                }

        }

        //lots of other stuff..
    }
```

This code that I have works in the sense: It only triggers if NumLock is Locked, and a MessageBox tells me which numKey I pressed. -But it doesn't bypass the RichTextBox like I want.

Comment: I can't disable the RTB, because I want to use both as a means of sending data to the server. RTB is the "more sophisticated, but slower" way of sending data - while the numpad can only send very basic quick commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the KeyPress event handler, set `e.Handled` to `true` when you think you have done everything and the RichTextBox shall not proceed with the key.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (_toBeIgnored)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}

private bool _toBeIgnored;

private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock))
    {
        _toBeIgnored = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: My method, userSentInput(), is registered to the RichTextBox as an OnKeyDown event. I tried moving the if statement to the top, and adding e.Handled = true, but that didn't work.

I tried creating a separe method, registered to the Form itself, but that also didn't work. I must be doing something wrong? (Will update the original post code with the new one.)

Comment: @Phrosen: agree, it seems that must be in the KeyPress event handler

Comment: The problem with KeyPress is: 'KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyData', so I don't know how to check if it was a numPad number or not.

Comment: You can have both methods, KeyDown and KeyPress - seems like you need to synchronize that in code, e.g. set a flag in KeyDown and evaluate it in KeyPress

Comment: I updated the code in the original post again. I changed the old userSentInput into rtb_inputField_KeyUp, and added rtb_inputField_KeyDown.
They trigger on KeyUp and KeyDown respectively.
I got rid of the KeyPress since I couldn't determine which key was pressed.

The current code still isn't working.

Could you please show an example of how to synchronize between KeyDown and KeyPress? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you.

The only problem I have now is that if I turn NumLock off on my keyboard, the RichTextBox interprets it kind like the arrow keys (so it's not outputting any numbers). I guess I can turn my methods around to check and see if NumPad is Unlocked, instead?

Comment: Yes, use `!IsLocked(...)`